# unix moving older files to a new directory causes error '... is not a directory'

Tags: unix, filesystems

I am trying to move files older than a certain date to a new folder and I keep getting the following error. mv: target '/*/*/*/*.*' is not a directory.
Here is my command line :

```
find /mnt/data1/sqlbackup/dataFiles/FOLDERII -mtime +300 -exec 
             mv -t '{}' /mnt/data1/sqlbackup/dataFiles/oldfiles \;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The argument after `-t` is supposed to be the destination directory. You're putting the source file there. BTW, you should probably have `-type f` in your `find`, otherwise it will try to move directories as well.

Comment: I am sorry if it seems I did not do much research effort here. I am not a unix user and was just trying to do this for the first time. I searched for this and got a confirmation post of this line working; so to the person who accepted the answer the mistake was by them.

Comment: thanks for the response Barmar

Comment: If you found this incorrect code in another question, can you post a link to it so we can try to get it corrected?

Comment: sorry it was on the unix.com forum find . -name '*.sql' ! -mtime -30 -exec mv -t '{}' /data/archive \;

Comment: thats fine though I will take the mark down; should have researched better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the order of the arguments. The argument after `-t` is supposed to be the desination directory that the files should be moved into.

```
find /mnt/data1/sqlbackup/dataFiles/FOLDERII -mtime +300 -exec 
         mv -t /mnt/data1/sqlbackup/dataFiles/oldfiles {} \;
```

Or you could just omit the `-t` option entirely. `mv` automatically treats the last argument as a target directory if it's a directory.

```
find /mnt/data1/sqlbackup/dataFiles/FOLDERII -mtime +300 -exec 
         mv '{}' /mnt/data1/sqlbackup/dataFiles/oldfiles \;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv), mv can be used in three ways:

> - mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
> - mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
> - mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

You are using it with the `-t` flag, so you need to pass the destination directory *before* the file(s) you want to move.